# The image exported using webdriver changed

Tags: webdriver

I am now using Sikuli and Webdriver to test Canvas automatically, export the web using Webdriver and then find the location by Sikuli, but the image exported changed a little which cause the finding failed.
If there is some setting can resolve this problem?

I can use only Sikuli to do test Canvas, but the screen must be opened, I don't want that, and Sikuli is not suitable for element operation.

Comment: the browser is chrome

Comment: After zooming in the picture, I found the icon did not change, but the pixels of the text changed. Is there any setting can make the picture completly same with the view in browser?